# Create a shareable URL from React Context State data

Tags: encoding, cryptojs

I've been staring at this for too long and think I've come up with a crazy solution...

Essentially, I'm using CryptoJS to encrypt my current React context state, creating a url that can be copied and shared.  It works perfectly fine, but as a solution I think it's probably overkill - Not to mention the param is over 6000 characters long!

Is there a better out of the box client-side solution for something like this?  Or alternatively, is there a way for me to tweak my current solution to seriously minimise the string created?

```js
    const generateUrl = () => {
        const encryptedState = CryptoJS.Rabbit.encrypt(
            JSON.stringify(state),
            ""
        ).toString();

        const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        urlSearchParams.set("config", encryptedState);
        const newUrl = `${
            window.location.pathname
        }?${urlSearchParams.toString()}`;
        window.history.pushState({ path: newUrl }, "", newUrl);

        return encryptedState;
    };

    const applySharedConfig = url => {
        const encryptedState = new URLSearchParams(url).get("config");

        const decryptedState = CryptoJS.Rabbit.decrypt(
            encryptedState,
            ""
        ).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        dispatch({
            type: HeaderAction.APPLY_SHARED_CONFIG,
            payload: JSON.parse(decryptedState),
        });
    };
```

Much appreciated.